# How to update Cookies after click logout button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am using Angular.js 1.2.9. I am creating cookies when  login.

```
$http.post('/api/login', $scope.new).then(function(response){
            $cookieStore.put('token', response.data.token,{expires: new Date(2017, 21, 01)});
            $rootScope.token=response.data.token;
            $location.path('/dashboard');

        }
```

and when user logout then I am removing it :

```
$cookieStore.remove('token'); 
      $rootScope.token=null;
```

After logout again  login with another credentials, then cookie is not getting update. After that, When I press `ctrl+R` [refresh page] then its shows updated user data otherwise it shows old user's data.

And in headers I am getting set cookie's data by which user data I am getting from db:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $cookieStore){
        return{
          'request':function(config){ 
            config.headers.authorization = $cookieStore.get('token'); 
            return config;
          }
        }
       })
```

In console dev tool cookie is not getting deleted till I reload the page.

Comment: Do you get the token removed after logout ? Could you provide some more code of where `$cookieStore.remove('token'); $rootScope.token=null;` is placed ?

Comment: `$cookieStore.remove('token'); $rootScope.token=null;` is placed on `logout` button click and full code of logout button is `app.controller('logoutCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $cookieStore, $location){
 $scope.logout=function(){
  $cookieStore.remove('token');
      $cookieStore.remove('currentUser'); 
      $rootScope.token=null; 
      $rootScope.currentUser=null; 
      $location.path('/');  
 }
});`

Comment: Cookies is removing but when I login again then its showing last loggedin user's info and when I reload page then its working fine.